# Webfrom : Having two textfield boxes inline .

Tags: webforms

What I need to do is have two input boxes next to each other.  As it's to except data that comes in two parts.  I can do this with CSS but using inline errors causes me problems. Has anyone done this or have any ideas on a solution.

[image]

Drupal 7 - webfrom 7.x-4.9+2-dev

Comment: Not really sure what your error is. If you define the two wrapping containers to be displayed inline, flexbox or via float (using css) it will not cause any errors with the processing itself. You also don't need to define your css inline, I would have it in a seperate stylesheet. However, there is a module called Field Groups where you can create a fieldset, div etc. to place the fields in. This makes putting two containers into one row, relatively easy as you isolate them from other input field containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this using the [Webform Layout](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_layout) module.

This module allows you to arrange fields into rows or columns.